# How to click all buttons that use ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a webpage that has 10 buttons to download a specific type of data to csv. 
However, I have to click every button to get all the files I need.

I am trying to build a script to download all the files but I am struggeling because all buttons are defined as this:

```
<a class="small" ng-click="aggTable.exportAsCsv(true)">
      Formatted <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download"></i>
    </a>
```

I was thinking about getting all elements with the class "small" and iterate through them with a for cycle but there are n elements with that class and I don't know how to click the ng-click.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not combine them all into one excel file with one button click?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a logic problem here. Why don't you wrap all the others functions in one?

```
function downloadFileA(){ //your code}

function downloadFileB(){ //your code }

function exportAsCsv(param1, downloadAll){
  if(downloadAll){
    downloadFileA();
    downloadFileB();
   }
}
```

If you still want to click multiple buttons, you can do it using jQuery and classes. 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgp5nLoc/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about making a new button that calls all the "aggTable.exportAsCsv(true)" onclick in a single function?